# Как добавить мультиязычность в Speech To Text от Google?

Tags: android, распознавание-речи

Для перевода речи в тексте используется Google Speech. Android на моем телефоне на английском языке, поэтому GS распознает только английский. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам задавал язык?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, stt_code);
try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```